# Calling (and catching) multiple promises

Tags: node.js, promise

I am trying to run below code (modified from [this link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies)):

```
let cnt = 1;

var prom = () => new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            console.log('enter promise ' + cnt);
            if (Math.random() < 0.5) throw new Error('error in promise ' + cnt);
            resolve('done in promise ' + cnt);
        }
        catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
        finally{
            cnt++;
        }
    }
);

prom()
    .then(prom())
    .then(function (fulfilled) {
        console.log('all done: ' + fulfilled);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    });
```

Basically I am trying to achieve a catch-all behaviour, i.e. if either promise fails, catch and stop processing. However can't achieve. What am I missing?

Comment: What is happening? Are you getting an error? What error?

Comment: Do not pass a promise to `then()`. Pass a callback *function* instead, e.g. `.then(prom)`.

Comment: this looks like the issue; can you make it an answer?

Comment: Which example exactly from the linked page did you use, and what and why did you modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) takes a callback as an argument and you gave it the returned Promise itself.

Use `.then(prom)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use Promise.all

```
return Promise.all([
  prom(),
  prom()
])
.then(([fullfilled1, fulfilled2]) => {
  console.log('all done: ' + fulfilled1 + ' ' + fulfilled2);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(error.message);
});
```

If one fails, everyone fails.